# Getting unique class names and looping through them

Tags: javascript, jquery, transformation

So I have this HTML:

```
<div class="videos">
    <div class="video year-2013">...</div>
    <div class="video year-2013">...</div>
    <div class="video year-2013">...</div>

    <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
    <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
    <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery should do the following transformation:

```
<div class="videos">
    <div class="videogroup group-2013">
        <div class="video year-2013">...</div>
        <div class="video year-2013">...</div>
        <div class="video year-2013">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="videogroup group-2012">
        <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
        <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
        <div class="video year-2012">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My plan was to get all the unique years connected to the `year-` classes (so an array of containing `2013` and `2012` in this case) and to iterate through each one, selecting the corresponding `<div>`s and then applying the transformation.

**My Question** is how can I use jQuery to create an array holding years from the `year-` class while making sure the values are unique and not manually entered?

Previously, I tried looping through all elements and grabbing their classes but that also included extra classes (like the `video` class). Not to mention, I wanted to just grab the year so that didn't help my case.

An example of what I tried previously:

```
var years = [];

$('[class*=year-]').each(function() {
    years.push($(this).attr('class'));
});

console.log(years);
```

The code fails because I'm storing whole classes and not removing duplicates - both things I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Select them all, then iterate over them generating an array of unique classnames. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have access to modify the server-side code? Unless this is a static html page, I would imagine there was already a loop to render these that you could tweak.

Comment: @JasonP I do have the server side code. When I posted the question, my intentions were that the web page looked a certain way without JS and if the end user did have JS enabled, it would be able to do some fancy things with it. That said, you've got me thinking and I might just make a server side change to make this a bit easier. Never the less, my original question still stands.

@KevinB My question is how can I do what you just described. I have tried selecting the all the elements using `$('[class*=year-]')` and that selects them all, but I'm at a bit of a loss from there.

Comment: Right, but that can be considered off-topic for this reason: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I get ya @KevinB, I'm improving my post with more information. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that I'm really happy with here. Thanks everyone for the responses.

```
var years = []; // He'll be holding our values soon.

// Loop through elements with the class `year-` in them.
$('.videos [class*=year-]').each(function() {
    var year = $(this).attr('class').match(/year-(\d*)/)[1]; // Regex gets the year (2013, 2012, etc.)

    // If the array doesn't have the year, we add it.
    if ($.inArray(year, years) == -1) {
        years.push(year);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I like a good javascript coding exercise in the morning:

```
// Find the unique classes
var uniqueClasses = {};
$(".videos div").each(function() {    
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each(classes, function(index, className) {
        // Ignore the "video" class
        if (className === "video") {
            return;
        }
        uniqueClasses[className] = true;  
    });    
});

// Restructure the DOM, wrapping each set of unique classes
$.each(uniqueClasses, function(className) {

    var groupClass = "group-" + className.split("-")[1];
    $("." + className).wrapAll($("<div/>")
                           .addClass("video-group")
                           .addClass(groupClass));
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/znxHL/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
var years = [],
    w = [];
$('.videos .video').each(function (i) {
    years[i] = $(this).attr('class').replace(/[a-zA-Z\-]/g, '').trim(' '); // get only the numbers
    if ($.inArray(years[i], w) === -1) w.push(years[i]); // move years in w without duplicates
});

$.each(w, function (i, year) {
    $('.videos .year-'+year).wrapAll('<div class="videogroup group-'+year+'"></div>'); // wrap items
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/q2paE/2/)

Comment: This is probably the best answer. The only issue is that the class Regex could've caused an issue (the classes are not set in stone and might change. I wouldn't want to pick up any other numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with no maintenance for another ~40 years!

http://jsfiddle.net/kvnBn/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var year = 2000; year < 2050; year++) {
        if ($('.video.year-' + year).length > 0) {
            $('.video.year-' + year).wrapAll('<div class="videogroup group-' + year + '"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

I was worried that this would be slower than string-splitting or regex solutions because of the unnecessary loops, but it takes only 1ms to run this in Chrome.

Comment: I want to make sure there's no manual work needed here. Thanks still!

Comment: @NessDan Edited with another version using the same concept that doesn't require maintenance.

Comment: Good until the year 2050! ;)

Comment: @pandavenger True, as long as you don't have future videos.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
function wrap(year){
    $('.year-' + year).wrapAll('<div class="group-' + year + '" />');
}

wrap('2013');
wrap('2012');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AeJCf/1/

Comment: Thanks, but in the question I stated that I didn't want to manually have to put in years.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create the array would be as follows:

```
var years;
$('.video').each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).getClass().split(/\s+/);
    for(x in classes) 
        if(x.indexOf('year') !== -1) {
            years[x] = x;
});
```

To later extract the individual elements iterate over years with $.each().

Comment: No such thing as `getClass()` and you're missing a closing bracket on the `if` statement.

Comment: Sorry, getClass() should be attr('class') the bracket was a typo.